# Linking cell to filename with specified substring? Excel

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

So what I'm trying to do is create a biography tracker sheet in Excel that holds links to the biography files in a certain folder. The names of the biography files are always changing because I record the status of that file in the filename next to the person's name (for instance "Sally Smith - First Stage Done.doc"). However, the person's name is always included in the filename and the name is unique within the folder. Is there a way to keep the link in the spreadsheet valid when the status changes by telling Excel to just link to the file containing the person's name as a substring?

All I've been able to attempt thus far is trying to use the HYPERLINK formula with a wildcard symbol, but that does not work. For example, if the name of the person Sally Smith is in cell A4, I typed: HYPERLINK("C:\Users\Evonna\All Bios\"&A4&"*"&".doc")

Comment: `=HYPERLINK(....)`?

Comment: I dont think you can use wildcards for hyperlinks. I would loop over the files in the expected folder using `Dir()` and choose the correct one with `If InStr(filename, Range("A4").Value2) > 0 Then`

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon I tried that, but the filename is changing. See above.

Comment: If the filename can't be hard-coded, and can't be constructed/concatenated from other values that exist in the worksheet, then no, it won't work and there's no way to make it guess what the file is...

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Oh, okay! I will try that.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon The file keeps the person's name; it's just the status at the end of the filename that changes

Comment: And is that status in the worksheet? If not, then @Marcucciboy2's solution will work, provided that you bail out of the loop once you find a match.